# PHP - Wrap Brackets around every comma

Tags: php, html, regex

Output 30|24|17,5|4|20,15|13|33,15|22|33,9|20|22

Let's say my output is that, Realistically every 3numbers is 1 Ticket they are seperated by a "," (comma)

I want to wrap parenthesis around them so the output would look like this

(30|24|17) (5|4|20) (15|13|33) (15|22|33) (9|20|22)

Would I have to use regex?

Comment: You don't HAVE to use RegEx. There are several ways to go about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try as follows,

```
$output = "30|24|17,5|4|20,15|13|33,15|22|33,9|20|22";
$string = "(" . str_replace(",", ") (", $output) . ")";
echo $string;
```

Comment: +1: just what I was going to suggest. NB PCRE's are usually much slower than the othe other string match/replace fns in PHP